# Convert Float to Integer Equivalent

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer

I want to convert a floating point user input into its integer equivalent.  I could do this by accepting an input string, say "-1.234" and then I could just explicitly convert each character to it's decimal representation.  (big endian by the way).  So I would just say for the example I gave,

```
-1.234 = 1|01111111|00111011111001110110110

sign bit = 1 = 128<<31
exponent bits = 01111111 = 127<<23
mantissa bits = 00111011111001110110110 = 1962934
decimal equivalent = 1962934 + 127<<23 + 128<<31
```

This is easy enough but unwieldy.  Is there a better way to do this?  Maybe some sort of type casting I can do?

Comment: What do you mean by integer equivalent?

Comment: Yeah, a bit fuzzy there, by equivalent I mean the integer equivalent of the 32 bit binary representation of a floating point number. As for my acceptance, I'll get on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float a = -1.234;
int b = *(int*)&a;
```

Also, in C++ there's this conversion operator that doesn't do any checks, `reinterpret_cast`. It's probably better here.

```
int b = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a);
```

Comment: At least in g++ I'm pretty sure you have to disable strict-aliasing for this to always work.

Answer (score 7):

A union lets you access the same piece of memory as different types

```
union floatint
{
   float f;
   int i;
}

floatint fi;
fi.f=-1.234;
int i=fi.i;
```

warning: you can get into weird platform differences and things like that because of size and alighnment, but since you're already making some assumptions by trying to interpret the float as an int, you may be able to get away with it.  Read more about unions, I think that's what you're going to want.

Comment: This is for the "OS" part of my processor simulation that I'm designing in verilog/c++.  I designed the processor to stringently follow the MIPSI ISA and I've also defined the architecture to follow the big endian convention so as long as I feed the type of integer equivalent I mentioned, I don't think I have to worry about anything else.

Comment: note, this only works for storing the float bit pattern in the int. (since all bit patterns are valid for ints) whereas if you store an int's bit pattern in a float, it may be altered since the compiler reinterprets it for the floats formatting. for example, the int 0xff810000 will be changed to 0xffc10000 when assigned into a float type. the only way to have precisely 0xff810000 (as far as i know) stored in the float is with memcpy. that way the compiler is just copying raw bytes, rather than reinterpreting/correcting the value for floating point storage.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to re-interpret bit patterns is to use memcpy. If I recall correctly, gcc allows the pointer-type-casting `*(int*)&a` as extension, but it is not guaranteed by the standard, and does not work with all compilers. Similarly, unions are not guaranteed to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float f = -1.234;
int i;
memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof i);
printf("bit pattern is: %d\n", i);
```

With optimization, the call to memcpy will be completely eliminated from the generated machine code.

Comment: I know that this is a C++ question, but since your answer can be read as a C answer, I will point out that unions **are** guaranteed to work in C. Footnote 82 in C99TC3 explicitly allows them for this sort of implementation-defined type-punning.

Answer (score 0):

In case you needed to convert a simple value, without an additional variable:

```
#define float_to_int(f) (*reinterpret_cast<const int*>(&static_cast<const float&>(f)))
```